# HAPI FHIR OpenAPI Document - Modifying Responses

Tags: openapi, watson-assistant, hapi-fhir

I have an OpenAPI document for HAPI FHIR that I am using to build a custom extension in Watson Assistant. Currently, when I make a call using this document, I only receive a "success" response. However, when I am examining the JSON response in the Extension Info from Watson Assistant, the full JSON response has a great deal more information than just "success." I would like to access that additional information.

Currently, the code for get CareTeam is:

```
    "/CareTeam/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "CareTeam"
        ],
        "summary": "read-instance: Read CareTeam instance",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "The resource ID",
            "required": true,
            "style": "simple",
            "schema": {
              "minimum": 1,
              "type": "string",
              "example": null
            },
            "example": "123"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "application/fhir+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FHIR-JSON-RESOURCE"
                },
                "example": null
              },
              "application/fhir+xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FHIR-XML-RESOURCE"
                },
                "example": null
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

However, when I examine the full JSON response, I get:

> {"status":200,"body":{"resourceType":"CareTeam","id":"va-team-visn6-vamc1-pc","meta":{"versionId":"1","lastUpdated":"2019-11-01T17:59:48.291+00:00","source":"#qsmu4cjPakjrXiTn"},"text":{"status":"additional","div":"<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hampton, VA, VAMC, Primary Care PACT"},"name":"Primary Care PACT","participant":[{"role":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://snomed.info/sct","code":"446050000","display":"Primary care physician"}],"text":"Primary Care Physician"}],"member":{"reference":"Practitioner/va-prac-visn6-francis","display":"Dr. Francis"}}]}}

I would like to be able to access all the additional data that currently exists in "body". I tried modifying the OpenAPI document to read:

```
    "/CareTeam/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "CareTeam"
        ],
        "summary": "read-instance: Read CareTeam instance",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "The resource ID",
            "required": true,
            "style": "simple",
            "schema": {
              "minimum": 1,
              "type": "string",
              "example": null
            },
            "example": "123"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "application/fhir+json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "status": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "body": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "resourceType": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "id": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "meta": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "versionId": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "lastUpdated": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "format": "date-time"
                            },
                            "source": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "text": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "status": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "div": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "name": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "participant": {
                          "type": "array",
                          "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                              "role": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                  "type": "object",
                                  "properties": {
                                    "coding": {
                                      "type": "array",
                                      "items": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                          "system": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                          },
                                          "code": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                          },
                                          "display": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    "text": {
                                      "type": "string"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              "member": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                  "reference": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                  },
                                  "display": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "example": null
              },
              "application/fhir+xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FHIR-XML-RESOURCE"
                },
                "example": null
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

but I get the same "success" or nothing responses.

How do I modify the OpenAPI document in order to do so? Is there a way to access that information via Watson Assistant without having to modify the OpenAPI document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `application/fhir+json"` is not supported, pls change to `application/json"`