# Not able to see response elements in watson assistant using custom extension

Tags: api, response, watson-assistant

I am facing same problem as
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126165/ibm-watson-assistant-custom-extension-variable-assignments" asked a fortnight before.
I am getting a complete json response but not able to access anything.

Below is my partial swagger having response details. Apart from 'ran successfully', no other response element is visible in extension object in watson assistant.

"responses": {
"200": {
"description": "OK",
"content": {
"application/json":{
"schema":{
"type": "object"
}
}
}
}
}

how can this be corrected.

What changes are needed in swagger or anywhere else? I tried correcting swagger by adding further details in response but no use.

Comment: How do you specify the results in your spec? Have you seen the spec for this tutorial? https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/blob/master/slackbot-openapi-spec.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add details of the object in `{ "schema":{ "type": "object" }` 
something like https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-toolkit/blob/master/integrations/extensions/starter-kits/spotify/spotify.openapi.json#L43-L66

Comment: Does it need to be the complete object or can it be a ref to an object schema that's being re-used?

Comment: @joseph it can be a reference